# Android 11 Runtime Permissions

Tags: android, kotlin, permissions, oppo

Before a few days, the code is working fine not having issues with permissions.

I am not able to grant permission at run-time also having issues while granting permissions from the setting. (App permission detail page).

```
var permissions = if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        arrayOf(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION)
    } else {
        arrayOf(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
    }
```

Requesting For Permissions on the appropriate button click.

```
permissionResultLauncher =
        registerForActivityResult(
                ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()
        ) { permissions ->
            var allPermissionGranted = true
            permissions.entries.forEach {
                if (!it.value) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Permission ${it.key} granted : ${it.value}")
                    allPermissionGranted = false
                }
            }
            if (!permissionDeniedDialog && !allPermissionGranted) {
                showDialog(
                        "Required",
                        "App needs Bluetooth and Location permissions to scan bluetooth devices.",
                        "Later",
                        "Allow",
                        object : DialogView.ButtonListener {
                            override fun onNegativeButtonClick(dialog: AlertDialog) {
                                dialog.dismiss()
                                val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS,
                                        Uri.fromParts("package", requireActivity().applicationContext.packageName, null))
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                                startActivity(intent)
                            }

                            override fun onPositiveButtonClick(dialog: AlertDialog) {
                                dialog.dismiss()
                                requestRequirdPermissions()
                            }
                        })
            } else {
                val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS,
                        Uri.fromParts("package", requireActivity().applicationContext.packageName, null))
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
            permissionDeniedDialog = true
        }
permissionResultLauncher.launch(permissions)
```

Function for checking permissions

```
private fun checkPermission(): Boolean {
        for (permission in permissions) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(), permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) return false
        }
        return true
    }
```

Can someone let me know why the above not working?. the system was on the result directly and the app was redirecting the app to the setting page, but I am not able to grant permission from the settings page too.

Is this OS Specific?, anyone having the same issues with ColorOS 11 ?.
Please guide me if anything is missing from my side.

Device: OPPO F17 Pro
OS: Color OS 11, Android 11 Based

**Note:**

Above code, with Samsung device, Android 11 Based (OneUI 3.1), App was not asking for runtime but after redirecting on setting page, I am granting location permission and app was working fine, regarding OPPO i am not able grant permission from setting page.

What tried :

```
  var permissions = if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    arrayOf(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION)
} else {
    arrayOf(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
}


private fun requestRequirdPermissions() {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            permissionResultLauncher.launch(arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION))
        }
        else
        {
            permissionResultLauncher.launch(arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION ))
        }
    }
```

Comment: _"Before a few days, the code is working fine not having issues with permissions"_. So what did you change since then?

Comment: Nothing changed, it was the same as previous, that's why I came here because I am checking since 2 hours.

Comment: You cannot request all different location permissions at one time. Read the doc.

Comment: Thanks but not sure, i have tried with single permission called ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION still not working.

Comment: @Ashvinsolanki you have to ask for location permission incrementally: ask for foreground (`ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`) then when granted you can ask for background (`ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION`). If you ask for background without foreground granted first or ask for both at once then request is immediately denied without even showing a dialog. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66321232/android-11-background-location-permission-allow-only-while-using-the-app-does/66321942#66321942

Comment: I will take care of your comment but after the system reset it was working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was fixed by the system reset, but according to comments and documents please follow the below guidelines for the location permission.

Thanks [Pawel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9241978/pawel) for comments,

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66321942/9909365

Background location permission does not work like other permissions. It's a request to elevate location permission from foreground-only to foreground & background.

User has to consciously select "Allow all the time" in order to do that and grant background location permission. Otherwise that permission is considered denied.

You cannot even request background location unless foreground location is already granted - when system permission activity shows up it should already have option 2 or 3 selected.

See https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions#request-background-location

**Note:**

When your app is using this background location please be prepared with a short video that demonstrates the location-based feature in your app that requires access to location in the background (while the app is not in use).

See https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9799150

Answer (score 1):

Try this way may help you

```
fun checkPermission() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            var permissions: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList<String>()
            permissions.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
            val listPermissionsNeeded: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
            for (p in permissions) {
                var result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, p!!)
                if (result != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    listPermissionsNeeded.add(p)
                }
            }

            if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                        this,
                        listPermissionsNeeded.toTypedArray(),
                        CODE
                )
            } else {
                next()
            }
        } else {
            next()
        }
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
            requestc: Int,
            permissions: Array<String>,
            grantRes: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestc, permissions, grantRes);
        when (requestc) {
            CODE -> {
                var isGrant = true
                if (grantRes.size > 0) {
                    for (i in 0 until grantResults.size) {
                        if (grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                            isGrant = false
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (isGrant) {
                    next()
                } else {
                    checkRationalePermission(permissions)
                }
            }
        }
    }


    var alertDialogRatinal: android.app.AlertDialog? = null
    fun checkRationale(permissions: Array<String>) {
        if (alertDialogRatinal != null && alertDialogRatinal!!.isShowing || permissions.size == 0) {
            return
        }
        var someDenied = false
        for (permission in permissions) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                    this@Activity,
            permission!!
                )
            ) {

            } else {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                        this@Activity,
                permission
                    ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                ) {
                } else {
                    someDenied = true
                }
            }
        }
        if (someDenied) {
            val alertDialogBuilder =
                    android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this@Activity)
            alertDialogRatinal = alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Permissions Required")
                    .setMessage(
                            "Please open settings, go to permissions and allow them."
                    )
                    .setPositiveButton(
                            "Settings"
                    ) { dialog, which ->
                    val intent = Intent(
                    Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS,
                    Uri.fromParts(
                            "package",
                            this@Activity.getPackageName(),
                null
                        )
                    )
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                startActivityForResult(intent, 100)
            }
                .setNegativeButton(
                    "Cancel"
            ) { dialog, which -> }
                .setCancelable(false)
                    .create()
            alertDialogRatinal!!.show()
        }
    }
```

Comment: i suggest you to use new API "ActivityResultContracts"

Answer (score 0):

```
private val requestIdMultiplePermissions = 1
private val permissionsRequest: ArrayList<String> =
    arrayListOf(READ_CALENDAR
            , CAMERA)
```

```
findViewById<Button>(R.id.multiplePermissionBtn).setOnClickListener {
            if (checkMultipleRequestPermissions()) {
                doOperation()
            }
}
```

```
 private fun doOperation() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
```

```
private fun checkMultipleRequestPermissions(): Boolean {
        val listPermissionsNeeded: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()

        for (p in permissionsRequest) {
            val result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, p)
            if (result != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                listPermissionsNeeded.add(p)
            }
        }

        if (listPermissionsNeeded.isNotEmpty()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                listPermissionsNeeded.toTypedArray(),
                requestIdMultiplePermissions
            )
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
```

```
override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if (requestCode == requestIdMultiplePermissions) {
            if (grantResults.isNotEmpty()) {
                var isGrant = true
                for (element in grantResults) {
                    if (element == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                        isGrant = false
                    }
                }
                if (isGrant) {
                    doOperation()
                } else {
                    var someDenied = false
                    for (permission in permissions) {
                        if (!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                                this,
                                permission
                            )
                        )  {
                            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                                    this,
                                    permission
                                ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED
                            ) {
                                someDenied = true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (someDenied) {
                        settingActivityOpen()
                    }else{
                        showDialogOK { _: DialogInterface?, which: Int ->
                            when (which) {
                                DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE -> checkMultipleRequestPermissions()
                                DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE -> { }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

```
 private fun settingActivityOpen() {
        Toast.makeText(
            this,
            "Go to settings and enable permissions",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
        )
            .show()
        val i = Intent()
        i.action = Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT)
        i.data = Uri.parse("package:$packageName")
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY)
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS)
        startActivity(i)
}
```

```
private fun showDialogOK(okListener: DialogInterface.OnClickListener) {
        MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this)
            .setMessage("All Permission required for this app")
            .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", okListener)
            .create()
            .show()
}
```